# proving discrete mathematics or giving counter example

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or find a counterexample: For all real numbers x and y it holds that
x + y is irrational if, and only if, both x and y are irrational.

can anyone explain to me or give a hint on how to start with this question or a answer would be great.

Comment: What the.... I swear, this EXACT question was posted a few days ago... counterexample $\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: The one I saw did not say if and only if.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for all $x$ , we have $x-x=0$

Answer (score 1):

$1+\sqrt{2}$ is rational or irrational?

$\sqrt{2}+(-\sqrt{2})$ is rational or irrational?

Comment: so my answer is let x= sqare root of 2 and y  be equal sqare root -2. so x+y= sqare root of 2 + sqare root of -2 is equal to zero which is not irrational. is this correct?

Comment: @user129834 Yes;a different example with positive numbers: $\sqrt{2}$ and $2-\sqrt{2}$ are irrational, however their sum is $2$.